# Flutter Bloc , Bloc state , navigate?

Tags: flutter, bloc

what I’m facing now is after I implemented bloc following one of the tutorials, I'm stuck now in place where after I'm getting the response and the state is changed, I want to navigate to another widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(APP_TITLE),
        ),
        body: buildBody(context));
  }
}

BlocProvider<SignInBloc> buildBody(BuildContext context) {

  return BlocProvider(
    create: (_) => sl<SignInBloc>(),
    child: Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<SignInBloc, SignInState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if(state is Empty)
                    return MessageDisplay(message: 'Sign In please.',);
                  else if(state is Loaded)
                    return HomePage();
                  else
                    return MessageDisplay(message: 'Sign In please.',);
                }
            ),
            SignInControls(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

in state of loaded I want to navigate to another widget.
so how to achieve that, and what is the best way for it?

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i'm trying to go for  HomePage() after the state became Loaded, but it's not working 
Because it's been add to the current widgets that's exciting on the screen and the screen would be overloaded with pixels.
I want to navigate to the HomePage as new screen.
I hope that make my question   more clear

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the navigator or change the state while the widget is being built (your case).
There're two ways

**1. The old fashioned way**

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
  // Your code goes here
});
```

**2. Since you already implemented the BLOC library** you have a more elegant way to achieve this by using [BlocListener](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocListener-class.html). you can learn more about it in the [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutternavigation)

Hope i helped!

Comment: BlocListener is much better.
Some times flutter won't redraw the UI, in that case, the navigation won't be triggered until you 'do' something to the app, like touching the screen or something. 
It's very troublesome when you're waiting for some progress bar and the screen doesn't udate until you touch it.

Comment: thanks @Ayham Orfali that was really  quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Navigation can be used like Inherited widgets:

```dart
Navigator nav = Navigator.of(this.context);
```

then you can use somthing like:

```dart
nav.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourSecondPage()))
```

in flutter, you can't just move to some page directly. you should use a route.

I think the cleanest way to use [named routes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes). this is an example:

```dart
// here you put a class of names to use later in all of your project.
class RouteNames{
    static String homepage = "/";
    static String otherPage= "/otherpage";
}
// in your main file , MyApp class
var routes = {
    RouteNames.homepage: (context)=> new MyHomePage(),
    RouteNames.otherPage: (context)=> new MyOtherPage()
};
// then use routes variable in your MaterialApp constructor 


// and later on in your project you can use this syntax: 
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteNames.otherPage);
```

I think this way is clean and it's centralized, it's good if you want to send arguments to routes.

To learn more about navigation: [navigation official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/)   is pretty good

**A note about the Bloc builder & listener:**

Since BlocBuilder is going to be called lots of times. it should only contain widgets and widgets only. if you put navigation code inside it, this code would be called multiple times.

As Ayham Orfali said You definitely should use BlocListener for that. Inside it you can listen to changes in state. here is an example

```dart
// some code
children: <Widget>[
            BlocListener(
                 bloc: BlocProvider.of<SignInBloc>(context),
                 listener: (context, state) {
                     if(state is Loaded){
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("some other page");
                     }
                       // else do nothing!
                 }, 
                 child:// just bloc builder which contains widgets only.  ,
            SignInControls(),
          ]

// some other code
```